# How do users can login automatically through URL when they click on the link received in Email

Tags: users

In Drupal 7, I am sending E-mail to each user with some content. Here I need to send link to automatically login through URL means when they click on the link they should redirect to the site and submit the form. This form should submitted by only authenticated users. How to generate those Unique URLs. Is there any module for this or give me any ideas please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Login one time](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_one_time) module

> Login one time provides the ability to email one-time login links to users. You can also choose the pages they will land on.

Another module is [urllogin](https://www.drupal.org/project/urllogin)

> This module provides a way to transparently log users into the web site when they follow a link. The primary use is for mass email where users are send individualized URL’s which take them to a page on the site, in a “logged in” state. Every effort has been made to minimize the potential security risks.

Comment: Ok. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: I used these modules but I wont need to login only once with that link. So I preferred urllogin module and downloaded csv file which gives me URL's for all users. If I login with any user URL from the CSV file, it is displaying as expired. Message showing as "The link you used to access this page has expired" in "Link to account" Page.

Comment: @JSinha I just installed urllogin module and tested that for you. just go to ***URL login settings***
(admin/config/people/urllogin) and give path to ***Optional destination for bulk generated links***. That's it. Now download csv file and test. That works. I tested it :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It is working fine, I need one more thing in which table these generated URL's will store for each user. I have to call those URL's with custom query.

Comment: @JSinha Glad to hear that!. If you feel it's useful please approve this answer. So that it would be useful for future readers.And ask about 'custom query' as new question. :)